# Scala complains "Unspecified value parameter num" when doing sum on a Set[Long]

Tags: scala

I have the following code

```
val a = (1 to 10)
a.toSet.map(i => new File(i.toString).length).sum
```

and it has compiling errors with Scala 2.12.4

```
 Error:(74, 15) missing parameter type
   a.toSet.map(i => new File(i.toString).length).sum
 Error:(74, 49) ambiguous implicit values:
   both object BigIntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type 
   scala.math.Numeric.BigIntIsIntegral.type 
   and object ShortIsIntegral in object Numeric of type 
   scala.math.Numeric.ShortIsIntegral.type
   match expected type Numeric[B]
   a.toSet.map(i => new File(i.toString).length).sum
 Error:(74, 49) could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[B]
   a.toSet.map(i => new File(i.toString).length).sum
 Error:(74, 49) not enough arguments for method sum: (implicit num: Numeric[B])B.
   Unspecified value parameter num.
   a.toSet.map(i => new File(i.toString).length).sum
```

I am guessing the compiler is complaining it cannot find a good candidate for `sum(implicit num: scala.Numeric[B])`. But if I just change `toSet` to `distinct`, the error will disappear. I don't quite understand how to explain this. I use `sum` instead of `sum()` in both cases.

Can anyone help me to explain the root cause of the error? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think, duplicate with [Missing parameter type error by calling toSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130013/missing-parameter-type-error-by-calling-toset)

problem is `toSet`

> Normally the rule is that the compiler should pick the most specific value. But since functions are contravariant in their argument, they are most specific when they take an Any as an argument, so the compiler can't decide.

Comment: I check the problem you linked and this should just be a duplicate. And your answer and other answers below indeed helps me understand the root cause of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Evgeny's answer, you can help the type inference like this:

```
val a = (1 to 10)
a.toSet[Int] /* ! */.map(i => new File(i.toString).length).sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Do we need a Set?

```
a.map {i:Int => (new File (i.toString)).length()}.sum // or:
a.map {i:Int => new File (i.toString).length}.sum
```

Comment: That's just an example demonstrating my problem. In real world I have duplicate entries and need a Set.

Comment: Well, a .toSet won't hurt here: a.toSet.map ... and as above.