# Illegal start of declaration

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala code:

```
object Solution {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val List(n, m) = readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt).toList;
        val knowledge: List[Set[Int]] = (0 until n).map( _ => {
            val knows: List[Char] = readLine().toList;
            (0 until m).toSet.flatMap(topic: Int => {
                knows(topic) match {
                    case '1' => Set(topic);
                    case _ => Set[Int].empty;
                } 
            });
        }).toList;
        val teams: List[Int] = knowledge.grouped(2).map{ case(x, y) => x ++ y }.map(_.size);
        val best: Int = teams.max;
        val count = teams.filter(_ == max);
        println(best + " " + count);
    }
}
```

On it, I am getting this error:

```
Solution.scala:16: error: illegal start of declaration
                knows(topic) match {Solution.scala:
```

On this line:

```
knows(topic) match {
```

I can not understand what is wrong.

I am using a `match` in a body of a `flatMap`.

Any idea what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with the explicit type, you'll need

```
(topic: Int) =>
```

as per the syntax for an anonymous function

https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/133

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13130013/5986907), you can also move the type to

```
(0 until m).toSet[Int].flatMap(topic => {
```

Comment: Another way is to write `.flatmap{ topic => ... }`

Comment: in some cases yes, but (and I don't entirely know why) the compiler can't infer the type here, so `: Int` is necesary

Comment: see `(0 to 10).toSet.flatMap(t => Set(t))` in the REPL compared to `Set(1, 2, 3).flatMap(t => Set(t))`

Comment: Oh..It's true..different behaviours in these two cases..cannot infer type in the first case..and it inferred type in the second case.what's happening here actually?

Comment: @RAGHHURAAMM i was pointed to this qu for the answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/13130013/5986907

Comment: But that seems to be a different case than this one..isn't it?Anyway I deleted it, after examining that question.

Comment: that qu is `List` to `Set`. this qu is `Range` to `Set`. Other than that they're the same

Comment: I am very happy to find that this community is so active in finding duplicates immediately..A good sign to learn effectively. Actually I search for any duplicates in the search box to avoid duplicates before posting my doubts..But the search suggestions box seems not so exhaustive?