# Why does converting a Seq to a Set and then calling map on same line not compile

Tags: scala

Say I define the following code:

```
val x: Seq[String] = Seq()
val y = x.toSet.map(s => (s, true))
```

This will not compile, giving me a *missing parameter type* error.

But if I break it down thus:

```
val x: Seq[String] = Seq()
val y = x.toSet
val z = y.map(s => (s, true))
```

it compiles fine. Why is this?

Comment: `toSet` can widen up the types thus when you chain the `map` that `map` is actually expecting a function from a new type `B >: A` that hasn't be defined yet. When you break the expression into two lines the compiler has to provide a type for `B` and since there isn't anything to help it infer the type it just picks `A` again and thus the next `map` calls already knows the type. I believe **Scala 3** is smart enough to do the right thing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note how there are multiple choices for which types fit

```
x.toSet[Any].map[(Any, Boolean]]((s: Any) => (s, true))
x.toSet[AnyRef].map[(AnyRef, Boolean]]((s: AnyRef) => (s, true))
x.toSet[String].map[(String, Boolean]]((s: String) => (s, true))
```

and as [Rex explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13130135/5205022) Scala 2 should

> ...pick the most specific value. But since functions are contravariant
> in their argument, they are most specific when they take an `Any` as
> an argument, so the compiler can't decide.

For example consider how because of argument contravariance function `Any => _` is more specific than `String => _`

```
implicitly[(Any => _) <:< (String => _)]   // ok
```

Inferring `Any` is never ideal so compiler asks the programmer for explicit help.

Now Scala 3 seems to have implemented Rex's suggestion

> There could exist a rule to break the tie ("prefer the early
> assumption"), but there isn't one implemented.

which makes it compile

```
scala> Seq.empty[String].toSet.map(s => (s, true))
val res0: Set[(String, Boolean)] = Set()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to rewatch the video at https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/type-inference.html which says it was 2019, but feels like a decade ago.